# JavaFX with FXML change css file runtime, with menu-items

Tags: css, javafx, runtime, menuitem, fxml

I'm learing JavaFx and I'm trying to change the css style of my window (Mastermind game) at runtime.

Currently it works with some objects like buttons, background, menu bar, labels and shapes.
But another object I'd like to change is the menu items (background and labels).

I've tried to use the next css code to acces it :

```
.context-menu {
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(rgba(200,200,200,1),rgba(50,50,50,1) 80%);
}
```

It works on initalisation but not when changed at runtime.
For example, it works fine for the menu bar itself :

```
.menu-bar {
    -fx-background-color: black;
    -fx-selection-bar: #505050;
}
.menu-bar .label {
    -fx-font-size: 12pt;
    -fx-font-family: "Segoe UI Light";
    -fx-text-fill: white;
    -fx-opacity: 0.9;
}
```

In the FXMLcontroller I call the following code to change the skin :

```
@FXML private AnchorPane generalPane;
private final String themeNormal = getClass().getResource("/mastermindStyles/MasterMind_Normal.css").toExternalForm();

@FXML
void handleSkinNormal(ActionEvent event){
   generalPane.getStylesheets().clear();
   generalPane.getStylesheets().add(themeNormal);
}
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found it :

To use predefinite styles (like Modena and Caspian) :

```
Application.setUserAgentStylesheet(STYLESHEET_MODENA);
```

To use your own css stylesheet :

```
Application.setUserAgentStylesheet(null);
StyleManager.getInstance().addUserAgentStylesheet(
  getClass().getResource("NewSkin.css").toExternalForm());
```